# PHP PDO getting different MySQL results than workbench

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

When running a query in phpMyAdmin workbench the results are as expected, a `total` has a value. However, when running the same code in PHP PDO `total` is always 0. Here's the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/18eeb6/1).

PHP Code:

```
        $stmt = "
SELECT COUNT(*) as `total`
FROM   `provider_availability`
WHERE  `provider_availability`.`practitioner_id` = :practitioner_id
       AND `provider_availability`.`weekday` = :weekday
       AND `provider_availability`.`ID` != :edit_id
       AND `deleted` = 0
       AND ( :start_time BETWEEN `provider_availability`.`starting_time` AND `provider_availability`.`ending_time`
        OR   :end_time BETWEEN `provider_availability`.`starting_time` AND `provider_availability`.`ending_time` )";


        $query = $this->connection->prepare($stmt);
        $query->bindValue(':practitioner_id', $_SESSION['user']['ID'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $query->bindValue(':weekday', $weekday, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $query->bindValue(':edit_id', $edit_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $query->bindValue(':start_time', $start_time, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->bindValue(':end_time', $end_time, PDO::PARAM_STR);

        if ($query->execute() == true) {
            $row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            return $row['total'];
        } else {
            die(json_encode([
                "success" => false,
                "reason" => $query->errorInfo()
            ]));
        }
```

Comment: Did you notice something? I'm not blaming PDO, I love PDO, it's made my life a lot easier.

Comment: As an aside, I wonder if you're really only interested in overlaps- so, where my_start < end and my_end > start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's impossible.

PDO will **never** get you a different result, given the query sent and the database connected to are the same.